# How to find the imrect rectangle position changed or not?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, roi

I am working on `imrect` function in matlab to display canny and sobel edge of ROI of `imrect` rectangle .
Actually I have two axis in my matlab gui. In one axis I am displaying user selected image and placing initial rectangle using `imrect` function on it. correspondingly  to the `imrect` rectange I am displaying canny edge or sobel edge on axis two. Everything is fine till now.
Now I want user to drag or resize the rectangle then automatically I want to dispaly the latest rectangle canny and sobel edges on axis 2.

How to find `imrect` rectangle position changed or not?

Can any one help me. If any web link will help please drop that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`addNewPositionCallback`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html) method to add your own callback function to be executed whenever the rectangle changes its position.

First, you need to create a function to be called with the new rectangle position:

```
function myFunc( newRect )
fprintf(1, 'New rect position = [%d %d %d %d]\n', newRect );
```

Now you can register the function with `imrect`:

```
rHandle = imrect(); %// create the interactive rectangle
addNewPositionCallback( rHandle, @myFunc ); %// register function myFunc to be called when rect is changed
```

Comment: Thanks Shai it's working that's alot for you solutions.

Comment: what if I have bunch of imrect on an image and I want to detect the changes in all of them and finally save those rectangles in a file?